# How to convert Objective-C block to Swift closure

Tags: swift, swift3, closures, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that contains an block which defined in Objective - C:

```
+(void)getNewList:(NewListRequestModel *)model returnInfo:(void(^)(NewListResponseModel* resModel))retModel;
```

and I invoke it like:

```
[API getNewList:model returnInfo:^(NewListResponseModel *resModel) {
      //code
}];
```

in Objective - C .

Now I want invoke it in Swift 3.2 :

```
 API.getNewList(model, returnInfo: {(resModel: NewListResponseModel) -> () in
       //my code     

  })
```

but I always got an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NewListResponseModel) -> Void' to expected argument type '((NewListResponseModel?) -> Void)!'
```

can some one help me the right way to invoke it? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift, closures can be very easily written. The compiler infers the parameter types and return type for you, so all you need to do is write the parameter name and `in`:

```
API.getNewList(model, returnInfo: {resModel in
    //my code     
})
```

You can also use the trailing closure syntax:

```
API.getNewList(model) {resModel in
    //my code
}
```

The error occurs because `resModel` actually is of an optional type. iN the original Objective-C code, `resModel` was a pointer, which can be null. When this is bridged to swift, it turns into `NewListResponseModel?`.

Answer (score 3):

//MARK: Class function to pass requestModel and get response model

```
class func getNewList(model: NewListRequesstModel, completion: @escaping (returnModel: NewListResponseModel) -> Void) {
           //Your code to get new model for retrun
  }

API.getNewList(model: newModelObject, completion: { (retunModelobject) in
       //your code 
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class func getNewList(model: NewListResponseModel 
  returnInfo: ((_ resModel: NewListResponseModel?) -> Void)?){
  }


API.getNewList(model, returnInfo: {(resModel) in
   //my code     

})
```

Comment: you mean rewritten it to swift function? but if I don't want rewrite it , just call the objective-c method. can you tell the right way?

Comment: import objective -c class in  bridging header file and call the function.